# SaveState in MvvmCross is not being called in an iOS application

Tags: ios, viewmodel, mvvmcross, lifecycle, savestate

I am using MvvmCross v3.5 to build an iOS application. Whenever the application goes into the background I am expecteing SaveState to be called in the view model.

However it never gets called. I have tried this both on the simulator and a device. Am I missing something.

This works in the Android version of the app, so I think I have set it up correctly.

Has anyone else got this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Xamarin you need to implement UIApplicationDelegate.ShouldRestoreApplicationState and ShouldSaveApplicationState to return true.

Comment: Thanks Tapani I'll give it a try tomorrow morning

Comment: Hi Tapani, I tried this and it is still not working. Is there anything else I need To do?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Xamarin, but when developing native you have to set the Restoration ID in storyboard/xib for those view controllers, which you wish to restore. The actual save/restore happens in encodeRestorableStateWithCoder and decodeRestorableStateWithCoder functions. I'm not sure how MvvmCross handles this internally. Not even sure if it has its own save/restore mechanism instead of iOS's. This tutorial explains how it works with Objective-C: [An iOS 7 State Preservation ... Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_State_Preservation_and_Restoration_Tutorial)

Comment: I should also say that i am not using a storyboard or .xib file, I am doing it programmatically

Comment: You can also set the restoration id in code: UIViewController.restorationIdentifier

Comment: I am beginning to wonder whether the MvvmCross SaveState and RestoreState view model lifecycle methods have been implemented for iOS. Can anyone confirm?