# Xamarin MvvmCross iOS state restoration issues

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, state-restoration

I am currently unable to get state save/restore working for an iOS (target iOS 8) Xamarin solution using MvvmCross. The core view model implements save/restore as specified here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle

The state is saved and restored correctly in the Android version of the solution, but is not working for the iOS version.

I have set a Restoration ID on the associated view controllers, and added the “opt in” methods to the app delegate class…

```
    public override bool ShouldSaveApplicationState(UIApplication application, NSCoder coder)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool ShouldRestoreApplicationState(UIApplication application, NSCoder coder)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

If I create a basic single view iOS Xamarin app then I do see a call to the view controller’s EncodeRestorableState override method when the app goes into the background. However, for a similar simple MvvmCross implementation, this overridden method is no longer called (and neither is the SaveState method of the view model).

I have been unable to find anything to help, and only seem to find many people asking similar questions, but currently with no answers (e.g. [SaveState in MvvmCross is not being called in an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901027/savestate-in-mvvmcross-is-not-being-called-in-an-ios-application)).

I would be very grateful for any information that could help point me in the right direction with this. Thanks.